# How do I ad rings to my cmdscale plot?

Tags: r, plot

I have created a [cmdscale plot](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/cmdscale.html), using a modified script I got online, in R that plots my pigment data from phytoplankton samplings.

(https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_nGJOKiTVD6cVFNY2dVV01seEE)

```
   d <- dist(fraktioneradRatio_15m2)
   fit <- cmdscale(d, eig = TRUE, k = 4)
   x <- fit$points[, 1]
   y <- fit$points[, 2]
   plot(x, y, main="Fractions 15m")
   city.names <- c("1", "2", "3",
                "4", "5", "6",
                "7", "9", "10",
                "11", "12")
   text(x, y, pos = 4, labels = city.names)
```

The plot works fine and looks good. I now want to add rings with set distances to them so the distances between clusters can be easily identified. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. And since it's a graphical question, putting in what you've already plotted and provide an example of what you intend to accomplish are essential.

Comment: I can´t add pictures until I get 10 reputation. I can only leave a link for now.

Comment: Still can't reproduce your coding without an example data to replace `fraktioneradRatio_15m2`. And what do you mean by adding "eings with set distance"?

Comment: What I meant was is there a way to add ring or circles around the clusters that are formed from the similarities indexes? Here is a link to the data i used. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_nGJOKiTVD6RkxjQkcyTnprc0U